# sharding with mongodb 3.2.22 doesn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, sharding

I'm using windows and mongodb 3.2.22
I want to run sharding in localhost
I executed these commands at the cmd terminal

```
mongod --replSet s0 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\1 --port 37017 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s0 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\2 --port 37018 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s0 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\3 --port 37019 --shardsvr --smallfiles

mongo 127.0.0.1:37017
config = { _id: "s0", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:37017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:37018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:37019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)


mongod --replSet s1 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\4 --port 47017 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s1 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\5 --port 47018 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s1 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\6 --port 47019 --shardsvr --smallfiles

mongo --port 47017 
config = { _id: "s1", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:47017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:47018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:47019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)


mongod --replSet s2 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\7 --port 57017 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s2 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\8 --port 57018 --shardsvr --smallfiles
mongod --replSet s2 --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\9 --port 57019 --shardsvr --smallfiles

mongo --port 57017
config = { _id: "s2", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:57017" },
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:57018" },
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:57019" }]};
rs.initiate(config)


mongod --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\c1 --port 57040 --configsvr --smallfiles
mongod --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\c2 --port 57041 --configsvr --smallfiles
mongod --dbpath C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\mongo3sharding\c3 --port 57042 --configsvr --smallfiles


mongos --configdb localhost:57040,localhost:57041,localhost:57042


mongo
db.adminCommand( { addshard : "s0/localhost:37017" } );
db.adminCommand( { addshard : "s1/localhost:47017" } );
db.adminCommand( { addshard : "s2/localhost:57017" } );

sh.addShardTag('s0','shard0')
sh.addShardTag('s1','shard1')
sh.addShardTag('s2','shard2')

sh.addTagRange("mydatabase.parole",{sentiment:"anger"},{sentiment:"disgust"}, "shard0")
sh.addTagRange("mydatabase.parole",{sentiment:"fear"},{sentiment:"sadness"}, "shard1")
sh.addTagRange("mydatabase.parole",{sentiment:"surprise"},{sentiment:"trust"}, "shard2")
```

the output of the sh.status () command is this:

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("5cd57e16918759db47284d69")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "s0",  "host" : "s0/localhost:37017,localhost:37018,localhost:37019",  "tags" : [ "shard0" ] }
        {  "_id" : "s1",  "host" : "s1/localhost:47017,localhost:47018,localhost:47019",  "tags" : [ "shard1" ] }
        {  "_id" : "s2",  "host" : "s2/localhost:57017,localhost:57018,localhost:57019",  "tags" : [ "shard2" ] }
  active mongoses:
        "3.2.22" : 1
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                2 : Success
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "mydatabase",  "primary" : "s0",  "partitioned" : true }
                mydatabase.parole
                        shard key: { "sentiment" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                s0      2
                                s1      1
                                s2      1
                        { "sentiment" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "sentiment" : "anger" } on : s0 Timestamp(3, 1)
                        { "sentiment" : "anger" } -->> { "sentiment" : "fear" } on : s0 Timestamp(1, 3)
                        { "sentiment" : "fear" } -->> { "sentiment" : "surprise" } on : s1 Timestamp(2, 0)
                        { "sentiment" : "surprise" } -->> { "sentiment" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : s2 Timestamp(3, 0)
                         tag: shard0  { "sentiment" : "anger" } -->> { "sentiment" : "disgust" }
                         tag: shard1  { "sentiment" : "fear" } -->> { "sentiment" : "sadness" }
                         tag: shard2  { "sentiment" : "surprise" } -->> { "sentiment" : "trust" }
```

I tried to insert a lot of data using this python code

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["parole"]

a=b=c=0
while a < 10000:
    dic={"sentiment" : "anger" , "test" : a}
    mycol.insert_one(dic)

    dic={"sentiment" : "fear" , "test" : a}
    mycol.insert_one(dic)

    dic={"sentiment" : "surprise" , "test" : a}
    mycol.insert_one(dic) 
    a+=1
```

insertion and replication work, but sharding does not work.
I understand this because folders 1,2,3 increase their size, but folders 4,5,6,7,8,9 do not change their size.

what can I do?
thank you! Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question myself.
sharding didn't work because the data wasn't enough.
use the command

```
db.settings.save ({_id: "chunksize", value: 1})
```

to reduce the size of the chunck

more information on this command in
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/modify-chunk-size-in-sharded-cluster/